# How to write a batch file to run vim commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, vim

I'm trying to write a batch file that will replace a couple of lines in a text file, using vim. Below is what I have for the batch file:

```
vim toedit.txt  
:10  
:R new value  
:11  
:R new value  
:wq
```

Executed, it will give a message from vim's point of view:

```
Swap file "toedit.txt.swp" already exists!  
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

What is swap file? Anyway, I press `D`, since it sounds like just a temporary file, then my batch run will stop in vim with the cursor on line 10 in the text file.

Does newline (which is produced by pressing enter) in the batch file function as the user pressing enter to run each command? How do I write up a correct batch file to edit the text file? Thanks.

Comment: To do some series of commands, you may go with macro in case of similar and repeating operations. Or, choose a function, or command line arguments also. You can specify what you want to do

Answer (score 5):

```
:help swap-file
```

Typically, swap file will be on the disk if Vim crashes, or opens a file that is already open by Vim in another process. You can ignore the swap file using the `-n` switch.

For batch editing, it will be better to use `ex`, which is the batch version of Vim. However, there is no `:R` command in vanilla Vim, so I can't be sure what you are trying to do; but it would be something like

```
ex -n toedit.txt +10 +"R new value" +11 +"R new value" +wq
```

Comment: ex is not a recognized command, it says. :R is to replace the whole line in the text file

Comment: You should be able to use `vim` instead of `ex` pretty equivalently. `:R` is not a built-in Vim command, so if that part doesn't work, can't help you.

Comment: *replace a couple of lines*: do they mean `:s/.*/new value`?

Comment: Is there an equivalent to print vim key bindings using `ex`? I'm trying to execute the equivalent of `:nmap` and exit, which I'm finding tricky with vim.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat `vim -es -u ~/.vimrc +"verbose nmap" +q` should do what you want. `:h -s-ex`, `:h -+c`, `:h :verbose` (at least in nvim). `-u ~/.vimrc` seems to be necessary for Vim (but not nvim), as Vim apparently skips vimrc when invoked with `-e`.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @Amadan. That works.